# how to pass array to this kind of definition array in subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

Recently, I find a f90 file which contains many special functions. I need to use `subroutine pbdv ( v, x, dv, dp, pdf, pdd )`, and I take a look at the definition of these six variables, the definition of dp and dv looks like these.

```
real ( kind = 8 ) dp(0:*)
real ( kind = 8 ) dv(0:*)
```

So how to call this subroutine with what kind of definition of array? The whole definition of this subroutine is [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/special_functions/special_functions.f90).

Comment: I find this question a little unclear at present.  Are you asking simply what `real x(0:*)` (simplified) means?  In terms of calling a subroutine with a dummy argument like that there's nothing particularly special.

Comment: @francescalus If I want to use this subroutine, I have to `call pbdv(v,x,dv,dp,pdf,pdd)`, but before I call this subroutine, I need to define these six variable. So what's the statement I need to write to define dv and dp? `real(kind=8)::dp(0:*)` seems wrong.

Comment: The dummy arguments are _assumed-size_.  You can read up on what that means.  Essentially, they assume their sizes from the things passed to them.  That is, there's no special declaration required in the place calling the subroutine.  There they are just normal arrays.

Comment: @francescalus but when I define an array, I have to specify the dimension and length of each dimension. But from `real(kind=8)::dp(0:*)` I don't know the length.

Comment: I would guess that this is because `pbdv` is designed to work for any length array, i.e. you decide what the length is for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @d_1999 I think your are right. I tried different length, they all work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a straight forward way. You could also make it non allocatable, and drop all the allocate stuff off of it.

```
PROGRAM MAIN
...
real ( kind = 8 ), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: dp
real ( kind = 8 ), DIMENSION(-2:80)          :: dv
...
ALLOCATE(dp(0:100))
...
CALL yourSub1('dp', dp)
CALL yourSub2('dv', dv)
...
IF(ALLOCATED(DP)) DEALLOCATE(DP)
END PROGRAM

SUBROUTINE YourSub1(Label, ddd)
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(LEN=*)                       , INTENT(IN   ) :: Label
real(kind=8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(INOUT) :: ddd

WRITE(*,22) Label, LBOUND(DDD, DIM=1), label, LBOUND(DDD, DIM=1)
22 FORMAT(' LBOUND(',A,')=',I7,' UBOUND(',A,'=',I6)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE YourSub1

SUBROUTINE YourSub2(Label, ddd)
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(LEN=*)          , INTENT(IN   ) :: Label
real(kind=8), DIMENSION(:), INTENT(INOUT) :: ddd

WRITE(*,22) Label, LBOUND(DDD, DIM=1), label, LBOUND(DDD, DIM=1)
22 FORMAT(' LBOUND(',A,')=',I7,' UBOUND(',A,'=',I6)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE YourSub2
```

Comment: How could this answer the question? This example does not contain a single assumed size array! (And the code us ugly.)

Comment: And rather importantly, there are no explicit interfaces available (except perhaps in the elided code section) in the main program for the external subroutines.  Such explicit interfaces are very necessary.

Comment: Maybe I do not see the point? Is it to pass in an array from 1:n and treat it like an array from 0:(n-1) ? And @Vladimir F which parts are specifically ugly? other than the real=8 which was in the context of the OP's style. It does give zmwang a way to see what the subroutine understands of the array, which was the intent of providing an example.

Comment: The question is clearly about how to call a subroutine with ` dp(0:*)`.

Comment: You have no indentation. Old FORMAT statements, superfluous RETURN statements. You are mising explicit interfaces to subroutines with allocatable and assumed shape arguments. After you move them to a module you can remove the IMPLICIT NONE.